# Why the (set-mark-command) throw errors?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I custom my forward-word as vim-like 'w'  follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931837/modifying-emacs-forward-word-backward-ward-behavior-to-be-like-in-vi-vim), this works fine except that M-S-f no longer selects text.
So, I write the function:

```
(defun forward-to-word-with-selection (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (if (not (eq last-command 'forward-to-word-with-selection))
      (progn (message "Mark Set")
             (set-mark-command))
    (forward-to-word arg)))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-F") 'forward-to-word-with-selection)
```

But, I got a messy error:

[image]

Then I run this function step-by-step(with C-c C-e, any other better debug approach is well come, since I'm newbie to elisp), this error due to the (set-mark-command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to manipulate the mark yourself.  Just specify "^" to interactive.  I've filed a bug with patch to fix it in Emacs, but you can define your own wrapper:

```
(defun forward-to-word-w (arg)
  "wrapper to work with shift-select-mode"
  (interactive "^p")
  (forward-to-word arg))
```

Comment: I means the highlighted code in the picture, like the `\205\202^@`.

Comment: I see. And can you tell how to debug the emacs with -Q? Currently I run each statement with `(C-c C-e)`. 谢谢～

Answer (score 1):

`set-mark-command` takes an argument containing the raw form of the prefix argument. That's how `C-@` acts differently depending on the type of prefix argument you give it.

You probably don't want to call this function in your code, you probably want to use `push-mark`.

Comment: But `push-mark` won't highlight the selection region as others' does. Otherwise after forward, I type C-x C-x

Comment: See the documentation of `push-mark` -- the third optional argument is whether to activate the region.

Comment: Not perfect with the `push-mark`, if I press `forward-to-word-with-selection`, and following the original point motion, `M-S-e` for example, the region-beginning will be reset.