# Emacs css-mode-syntax-table missing?

Tags: css, emacs

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1772365/257583), I can make C++ mode think that underscores are not variable delimiters by adding this line to .emacs:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" c++-mode-syntax-table)
```

That seems to work well enough. But when I try to do something similar to CSS:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?- "w" css-mode-syntax-table)
```

I get this error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: css-mode-syntax-table
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: did you care to load `css-mode` before you start customizing the variable.? if not wrap above code with `eval-after-load`

Comment: @kindahero you can enter that as an actual answer, haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kindahero said, I had to `(load css-mode)` before doing the above.

Comment: I run into the same error `Symbol's value as variable is void: css-mode-syntax-table` when trying to export to HTML from Orgmode.  I can't change to `css-mode`, since I need to export from `org-mode`.  `(load css-mode)` in my `emacs.d/init.el` gives me `eval-region: Symbol’s value as variable is void: css-mode`.  How can I make sure that `css-mode-syntax-table` is set when starting emacs, so that I can use it even when not in `css-mode`?

Comment: I found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812465/1386750): I had to remove the version of `css-mode` installed by my system in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/css-mode/css-mode.el`, which was preferred over emacs' own version in `/usr/share/emacs/27.2/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el`.  Then it worked.