# Emacs regex wordWord boundary (specifically concerning underscores)

Tags: regex, replace, emacs, boundary

I am trying to replace all occurrences of a whole word on emacs (say foo) using M-x replace-regexp.

The problem is that I don't want to replace occurrences of foo in underscored words such as word_foo_word

If I use \bfoo\b to match foo then it will match the underscored strings; because as I understand emacs considers underscores to be part of word boundaries, which is different to other RegEx systems such as Perl.

What would be the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 13):

The regexp `\<foo\>` or `\bfoo\b` matches `foo` only when it's not preceded or followed by a word constituent character ([syntax code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html) `w`, usually alphanumerics, so it matches in `foo_bar` but not in `foo1`).

Since Emacs 22, the regexp [**`\_<foo_bar\_>`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) matches `foo_bar` only when it's not preceded or followed by a symbol-constituent character. Symbol constituents include not only word constituents (alphanumerics) but also punctuation characters that are allowed in identifiers, meaning underscores in most programming languages.

Answer (score 6):

You wrote:

> as I understand emacs considers underscores to be part of word boundaries, which is different to other regex systems

The treatment of underscores, like everything else in emacs, is configurable.  This question:
[How to make forward-word, backward-word, treat underscore as part of a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1545851/48082)

...asks the converse.

I think you could solve your problem by changing the syntax of underscores in the syntax table so that they are not part of words, and then doing the search/replace.

To do that, you need to know the mode you are using, and the name of the syntax table for that mode. In C++, it would be like this:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "." c++-mode-syntax-table)
```

The dot signifies "punctuation", which implies *not part of a word*.   For more on that, try `M-x describe-function` on `modify-syntax-entry`.