# Deleting back or forward / moving back or forward a string containing only non-space characters in emacs

Tags: emacs, editor

A character string like:

```
string1_string2_string3
```

is not considered as a word in emacs.

Deleting one "word" from the start point only deletes "string1". How can I delete to the end of "string3" from "string1" or vice versa? The same problem occurs when moving forward or backward.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545851/how-to-make-forward-word-backward-word-treat-underscore-as-part-of-a-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>C-M-k</kbd>, which is `kill-sexp`.  Similarly, you can move around with <kbd>C-M-f</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-b</kbd> (bound to `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp` respectively).

Or make the change proposed for a solution to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545851/how-to-make-forward-word-backward-word-treat-underscore-as-part-of-a-word).

Answer (score 0):

You could just hit `M+d` three times instead of one.