# Underscore as part of word for forward-word not working

Tags: emacs, emacs23, nxhtml

I am trying to make underscores get treated as part of the word for the `forward/backward-word` function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545851/how-to-make-forward-word-backward-word-treat-underscore-as-part-of-a-word) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545851/how-to-make-forward-word-backward-word-treat-underscore-as-part-of-a-word).  I am specifically trying to get this to work for `nxhtml` mode, but would really like it to work like this for all modes.

I have modified my `site-start.el` file a number of different ways but to no avail.  But if I manually execute the command `M-x modify-syntax-table` in the buffer, it works just fine. I just can't get this to be the default behavior.

Here is what I tried putting in my `site-start.el` file:

```
;; 1
;; thought  this would apply it to all modes - no error, but did not work
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w") 

;; 2
;; thought this would automatically set it on a mode change - no error, but did not work
(defun change-major-mode-hook ()
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w"))


;; 3
;; thought  this would apply it to all modes - no error, but did not work
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")

;; 4
;; this produced a symbol's value as variable is void error
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" nxhtml-mode-syntax-table)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The docstring of `modify-syntax-entry` says "The syntax is changed only for table SYNTAX-TABLE, which defaults to the current buffer's syntax table". There's nothing there to suggest you could globally change all syntax tables by omitting that parameter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried modifying the `nxhtml-mode-hook` directly?  Like so:

```
(add-hook 'nxhtml-mode-hook
          (lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))
```

Comment: Thanks - this did just what I was looking for.  And I added:
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
          (lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")))

Comment: I would like for someone to clarify: Does this work for all Emacs modes, or only for the `nxhtml-mode`? (I am guessing the latter, but please clarify)

Answer (score 6):

Trey's answered your very specific question.

But Emacs already has a level of character organization that does what you ask: sexp.  If you learned sexp commands instead of *breaking* word commands, then you can delete by "word" or by "symbol" as the situation fits.

Comment: When using variable names with underscores, I really want to treat the underscore as part of the word.  The symbol-based movements are just too drastically different from what I am used to.

Comment: I found treating an underscore as a separate word very inconvenient. I couldn't even remember when I actually was needed to move to half of a word `foo_bar` *(btw, currently I have really many such a words)*. But conversely: every time I'm moving, or trying to do something with a text object in Emacs's Evil, and I have such a word around — this thing just interferes in my editing and slows me down.

Answer (score 4):

As event_jr, I recommend you learn to use the sexp-based commands like `C-M-f` and `C-M-b`.  But if you really want to only jump over identifiers (and ignore things like parentheses), then rather than try and change all syntax tables in all major modes (which may end up having unforeseen consequences), I recommend you simply use new symbol-based movement commands.
E.g. `(global-set-key [remap forward-word] 'forward-symbol)`.  For some commands (like `kill-word`) you'll need to write `kill-symbol` yourself, but it should be easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding hooks for each major mode, as suggested by Trey Jackson, you can modify the standard syntax table. The different modes inherit from the standard syntax table so your modification will hopefully apply to all modes:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" (standard-syntax-table))
```

This will affect regular text, XML, Python and others.

Some modes are more stubborn, and modifying the standard syntax table won't affect them as they override some symbols during initialization. One example is `cc-mode`. You'll still have to modify their tables explicitly.