# iOS - regex to match word boundary, including underscore

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have a regex that I'm trying to run to match a variety of search terms.  For example:

the search "old" should match:
-> age_old
-> old_age
but not
-> bold - as it's not at the start of the word

To do this, I was using a word boundary.  However, word boundary doesn't take into account underscores.  As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545851/how-to-make-forward-word-backward-word-treat-underscore-as-part-of-a-word), there are work arounds available in other languages.  Unfortunately, with NSRegularExpression, this doesn't look possible.  Is there any other way to get a word boundary to work?  Or other options?

Comment: Why not possible? Use `(?<![\\p{L}\\d])` at the beginning and `(?![\\p{L}\\d])` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by "start of the word", precisely?

Comment: @BradThomas as in my example, "old" should match bold.  But it should match _old, for example

Comment: What about 1old, ?old, *old, Old, olden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: Use one of the following:

```swift
let rx = "(?<=_|\\b)old(?=_|\\b)"
let rx = "(?<![^\\W_])old(?![^\\W_])"
let rx = "(?<![\\p{L}\\d])old(?![\\p{L}\\d])"
```

See a [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/SNTkKz/2), [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/SNTkKz/1) and [regex demo #3](https://regex101.com/r/SNTkKz/3).

Swift and Objective C support [ICU regex flavor](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp). This flavor supports look-behinds of fixed and constrained width.

> `(?= ... )`     **Look-ahead assertion**. True if the parenthesized pattern matches at the current input position, but does not advance the input position.
>
> `(?! ... )`    **Negative look-ahead assertion**. True if the parenthesized pattern does not match at the current input position. Does not advance the input position.
>
> `(?<= ... )`    **Look-behind assertion**. True if the parenthesized pattern matches text preceding the current input position, with the last character of the match being the input character just before the current position. Does not alter the input position. **The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no * or + operators.)**
>
> `(?<! ... )`    **Negative Look-behind assertion.**

So, you can use

```
 let regex = "(?<![\\p{L}\\d])old(?![\\p{L}\\d])";
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV5zW9/1)

Here is a [Swift code snippet](http://swiftstub.com/347032427) extracting all "old"s:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
            options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

let s = "age_old -> old_age but not -> bold"
let rx = "(?<![\\p{L}\\d])old(?![\\p{L}\\d])"
let matches = matchesForRegexInText(rx, text: s)
print(matches) // => ["old", "old"]
```

Comment: thanks, this seems like its working.  I'm testing it now

Comment: Hey so this is definitely working for NSRegularExpression.  I'm trying to run this in coredata with a "matches %@" predicate, and it doesn't seem to return the values.  After some testing it seems like the match range has to return the entire string to be returned from core data.  Any idea how to extend the match to the entire string, given the same criteria?

Comment: Add `^.*` at start and `.*$` at the end of the pattern and use .DotMatchesLineSeparator option to allow `.` to match any existing character.