# Looking for ranges of matching word in a string

Tags: swift, regex, string

I need to make a function that returns me ranges of matching words in a given string, for example, given the sentence below:

> Hey, bro! Your brother is also her brother.

I want to find an array of `Range` in the sentence that matches the word "bro", it should match the exact word (case insensitive), so "bro" should only match "bro" but not "brother".

I thought about:

1. split the sentence, e.g. `"hey", "bro", "your", "brother", "is", "also", "her", "brother"`
2. map each word to a word with range, e.g. "hey" would become `["hey", 0...2]`
3. filter and map the word and range array, matching "bro"

Step 2 needs some treatment to make sure the range for each word (in the sentence) can be mapped to the right word, e.g. the first "brother" and second "brother" should have different ranges depending on where they are located.

Is there any smarter way of doing this?

The reason for not using Regex was that sometimes the word has a dot in it, for example:

> there is orange in the basket.

from the above sentence, finding the string "or.ge" using regex would match "orange" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is to use regular expressions with `\b` to match “word boundaries”, e.g.

```swift
let searchString = "bro"
let sentence = "Hey, Bro! Your brother is also her brother."

let regex = Regex {
    Anchor.wordBoundary
    searchString
    Anchor.wordBoundary
}.ignoresCase()

// Or you can use traditional regex string patterns:
//
//     let regex = try! Regex(#"\b"# + searchString + #"\b"#)
//         .ignoresCase()
//
// Note, this is not identical to the above, as the former
// escapes and regex patterns within the search string, but 
// this does not.

for match in sentence.matches(of: regex) {
    print(sentence[match.range])    
}
```

Or, if you want, you can use `NSRegularExpression`:

```swift
let searchString = "bro"
let sentence = "Hey, Bro! Your brother is also her brother."
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"\b\#(searchString)\b"#, options: .caseInsensitive)
regex.enumerateMatches(in: sentence, range: NSRange(sentence.startIndex..., in: sentence)) { match, _, _ in
    guard let match = match else { return }
    print(match.range)

    // or, if you want a String.Range

    if let range = Range(match.range, in: sentence) {
        print(sentence[range])
    }
}
```

There are other richer API (e.g. the [Natural Language](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage) framework), which, while not perfect, provide richer parsing of natural language text. For example, the below will differentiate between the verb “saw” and noun “saw”:

```
import NaturalLanguage

let text = "I saw the hammer. I did not see a saw."

let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.lexicalClass])
tagger.string = text
let options: NLTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .joinContractions]
tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .lexicalClass, options: options) { tag, range in
    guard let tag = tag else { return true }

    print(tag, String(text[range]))
    return true
}
```

Producing:

> NLTag(_rawValue: Pronoun) I 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Verb) saw 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Determiner) the 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Noun) hammer 
> NLTag(_rawValue: SentenceTerminator) . 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Pronoun) I 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Verb) did 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Adverb) not 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Verb) see 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Determiner) a 
> NLTag(_rawValue: Noun) saw 
> NLTag(_rawValue: SentenceTerminator) .

Comment: Thanks, this works for most of my samples, but I there are cases like finding word "sh.it" (dot in between) in sentence `"shit on shirt"` causing "shirt" to be matched because the dot matches anything, I guess I need to escape the dot?

Comment: Yep, you need to escape `.`, `?`, `+`, `{`, `[`, `(`, etc., if you're really searching for any string. I thought you were searching for words...

Comment: Or you can use the `Regex` with `Anchor.wordBoundary` pattern, shown in my revised answer, and then you do not need to escape the various characters listed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in Playground, You can use this extension to get the values matching this reg ex.

```
extension String {
    func ranges(of substring: String, options: CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        while ranges.last.map({ $0.upperBound < self.endIndex }) ?? true,
              let range = self.range(of: substring, options: options, range: (ranges.last?.upperBound ?? self.startIndex)..<self.endIndex, locale: locale)
        {
            ranges.append(range)
        }
        return ranges
    }
}

let searchString = "bro"
var str = "Hey, bro! Your brother is also her brother."
var reg = str.ranges(of: "(?<![\\p{L}\\d])\(searchString)(?![\\p{L}\\d])", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive])

str.removeSubrange(reg.first!)

print(str)
```

Credits to,
[iOS - regex to match word boundary, including underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767112/ios-regex-to-match-word-boundary-including-underscore)